# cursor moves after trim in textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a piece of code that checks every character entered into a textbox and if its anything but a number it pops a msg box saying "blank" is not numeric. After this it resets the cursor to the start of the textbox and i would like to have the cursor placed at the end of the textbox's current text.

```
string actualdata = string.Empty;
char[] entereddata = txfanrpm.Text.ToCharArray();
foreach (char aChar in entereddata.AsEnumerable())
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(aChar))
    {
        actualdata = actualdata + aChar;          
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(aChar + " is not numeric");
        actualdata.Replace(aChar, ' ');
        actualdata.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `txtfanrpm.Select(...)`?

Comment: You don't need to do all of that conversion at the top. A `string` is inherently a `char[]`, so `foreach (char c in actualData)` will enumerate fine.

Comment: You could just use as masked text box: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set selection start to length of text:

```
txfanrpm.SelectionStart = txfanrpm.TextLength;
```

NOTE: You don't need to convert text to char array - string is already `IEnumerable<char>`

```
foreach(char ch in txfanrpm.Text)
{
     if (!Char.IsDigit(ch))
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ch + " is not numeric");
          continue;
     }

     actualdata += ch;
}
```

Alternative solution - two loops, but more efficient string creation:

```
foreach(char ch in txtfanrpm.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)))
     MessageBox.Show(ch + " is not numeric");

string actualdata = new String(txtfanrpm.Text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: thank you the selectionstart works great, and thanks for the help on simplifying my char filter, i had actually found that elsewhere on  SO and had just made it work in my program.